# Is there a way to use regex expressions to auto-fill filenames in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, regular-expression, filenames, autocomplete

Assuming I have a directory with files as shown:

```
$ ls
file0001.txt file0002.txt file0003.txt file0004.txt file0005.txt someotherfile.txt
```

Lets say I want to run the following command:

```
$ cat file0001.txt file0002.txt file0003.txt file0004.txt file0005.txt
```

I could achieve this using a bash shortcut as follows to auto-fill the file names: `cat file000` <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>

Now would it be possible to use a shortcut in a similar way to only autofill according to some regex (regular expression)? For example: `cat file000[1-3]` <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> to get:

```
$ cat file0001.txt file0002.txt file0003.txt
```

<sub>Edit: The regex I should have used above for this example to make more sense: `file000[1-3].txt` or `file000[1-3]*`</sub>

**Just to be clear my question is about how to auto-fill on the bash with regex. And NOT how I can `cat` some files together using a bash script or `for`/`while` statements using regex.**

Comment: This IS an option in ZSH as I can type in cat .file*.[t][x][t] and hit tab and it will auto fill all of it for me. I don't know what configuration I have in my .zshrc file but it is possible. I can't get this to work in bash. Zsh also allows you to combine multiple stars such as ls **/*/*.

Comment: I just noticed that all of this is about file globing patterns and not regex, strictly speaking. Gave my answer none the less :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is there. You are just missing a `*` in your example. Type `cat file000[1-3]*`<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> and it should work. I think this is the case because the readline function `insert-completions` (which is bound to <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>) will not expand the glob pattern if it does not match any files. And without the last `*` it does not match the files.

You can read about this in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), section "EXPANSION" subsection "Pathname Expansion".

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it's not *necessary* to "insert completions" to run the command; the shell will expand globs before the command sees them anyway.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Under Bash 4.3.42 (Debian sid), a `cat file000[1-3]*`[Esc][\*] expands only to the first matching file, under Bash 4.2.37 (Debian 7.5) there is no expansion at all. If I press [Enter] instead of [Esc][\*], the correct files are `cat`ed. In both cases with default shopt settings.

Comment: @Dubu sorry I don't know why. I'm on Arch Linux with Bash `4.3.42(1)-release`. I tried it even without a `~/.inputrc` file and a clean environment: `env --ignore-environment bash --norc --noprofile` and `bind -p|grep -F '*'` prints `"\e*": insert-completions` among other lines.

Comment: @Lucas Seems to be a Debian problem. It works when I use your clean environment. I'm trying to find the difference ...

Comment: Okay, apparently Debian's bash completion settings overrule something so that [Esc][\*] does not work as intended. (I assume the solution can be found somewhere along the almost 2000 lines of the `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` file, but I do not have the time to debug.)

Comment: Lucas and Dubu thank you for the very useful info. I am also trying this on one of my debian based machines (Ubuntu 14.04) and I am having the same problem as Dubu. Might just accept this as answer if I don't find a better solution for debian. And sorry about the regex mistake Lucas ;)

Answer (score 1):

Braces are what you need

```
cat file000{1,2,3}.txt
```

This gets converted to:

```
cat file0001.txt file0002.txt file0003.txt
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. From my post: "Just to be clear my question is about how to auto-fill on the bash with regex. And NOT how I can cat some files together using a bash script or for/while statements using regex.". Whats key here is that I need the command to auto-fill. If you try cat file000 ESC * you will see the kind of auto-fill I'm looking for.